# Neo4j User Defined Function cannot be installed

Tags: graph, neo4j, user-defined-functions, graph-databases

I am trying to create a user defined function in Neo4j. I did it exactly as they did it in their examples: [Neo4j Procedure Template](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-procedure-template). After deploying and creating the JAR I copied the JAR into the plugins folder at `neo4j-community-3.4.9/plugins/` and also in `neo4j-community-3.4.9/data/databases/graph.db/plugins/`. But the functions are not displayed when typing `CALL dmbs.functions()` or trying to use it like `return example.join(['a','b'])` it just says following:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Unknown function 'example.join' (line 1, column 16 (offset: 15))
"return example.join(['a','b'])"
```

Comment: Did you restart the neo4j server after copying the JAR files?

Comment: @cybersam Yes i did